Chinese movie where Wukong is fighting an army and throws his master away to save him
I remember a movie I watched around 2014 but couldn't remember its name. I think it's a Chinese movie.
It seems like a Monkey King movie. I remember a scene in which I think Wukong is fighting an army, but they are powerful, and he does not seem to be able to defeat them. So he picks up his master and throws him far away from the enemies.
It might not be a Monkey King movie, but I remember that when he throws away the master, the master starts chanting some mantra that affects the headband of Wukong and starts hurting him. This makes me think that it must be a Monkey King movie.

Hi, welcome to Movies & TV.  When did you watch this?  (We don't know when you were a child.)

I don't exactly remember but maybe at around 2014.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey_King_(2014_film)

I couldn't find the mentioned scenes in this movie.

I'd actually forgotten the mantra bit, (but not the circlet), hence the incorrect answer
